# Aliased HUD icon?

Tags: unity, hud

I am currently on Ubuntu 12.04 with Unity 3d and today I noticed that the icon next to the HUD is slightly artefacted and aliased, unlike the other icons in the dash.

I was wondering if i'm the only one affected by this and if not, is it a know bug or should a report be made?

My graphics card: Intel HD 3000 + Nvidia Gtx425. Unity runs on the integrated one.

PS: This seems to appear only in autohide mode, not in always on.

[image: Example]

Comment: Mine is the same would also like to know why. But mine looks like dash home icon as opposed to firefox icon eg more rounded icon in hud than unity bar.

Comment: @markkirby it shows the icon of application which is in focus. HUD is application specific.

Comment: Well I guess it depends on what application it stands for, as the HUD interacts with the indicators(clock, session menu) too.

Comment: The icons there look ok to me.

Comment: @John S Gruber It's because theimages on this site apparently can't be properly zooomed.On screen it is really jagged. http://ge.tt/3pNGqgL/v/0?c Zoom on this one.

Comment: @vitiv I wasn't at all clear. I'm sorry. I meant to say that I don't see it on my computer--so it isn't a universal problem though we can tell from  mark's comment that it's not just your system either.

Comment: Is that a Faenza icon? Have you done something to change the default icons?

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).